# What version of Delta Lake is supported by Synapse built-in SQL pool

Tags: azure-synapse, delta-lake, azure-synapse-analytics

I'm using Synapse Analytics to read from a Data lake containing Delta tables. The Delta tables were written using the latest Delta version.

How can I verify what version of Delta is running in the Built-in serverless SQL pool?

[image]

I tried searching through the Microsoft Docs and was not able to find anything. Is there a SQL command I can run to find out?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Synapse Analytics, the version of Delta Lake supported in the Built-in SQL pool is tied to the version of Apache Spark that is used by the spark pool.

You can find supported delta lake version for Apache spark at properties of pool:

[image]

Delta Lake supported in the Built-in SQL pool does not depend on the collation used by the database, but rather on the version of Apache Spark used by the pool. As per above built-in sql pool supports delta lake version 2.2. you can find more information [here](https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html).

Comment: While this is a great answer for Spark pools, the Built-in Serverless SQL engine is not related to this configuration.

Comment: Thanks for you answers, I agree with Joel though in that this answer is related to the Spark pools. For argument sake let's say what you're saying is true, is there a way to verify the connection the exact Spark pool used? Let's say I have 2 Spark pools, how can I verify which one is used by the buil-in serverless pool?